# Highcharts - position icon element in the title

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I am having 11 charts with icon in the chart title, I was wondering how to apply some css to place those icons to the left, right above y axis with numbers, so that title text stays in the center, without having to make a class for each icon. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mu9wswv3/8/) is the example. This is the code:

```
$(function () {

  //set of common options
    Highcharts.setOptions({
    chart: {
        type: 'boxplot'
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    title: {
      useHTML: true,
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015'],
      title: {
          text: 'Experiment No.'
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      plotLines: [{
        color: 'red',
        width: 1,
        label: {
            align: 'center',
            style: {
                color: 'gray'
            }
        }
      }]
    },
    series: [{
      color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
      type: 'scatter',
      marker: {
          fillColor: 'white',
          lineWidth: 1,
          lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
      }
    }]
  });

  //plotline options
  var plotLinesOption = {
    width: 1,
    color: 'red'
  };

  var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'indikator1',
    },
    title: {
      text: '<span data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip" data-disable-hover="false" tabindex="1" title="Help text that goes next to the chart title"><i class="ion-help"></i></span> Arbeidsmarkedsintegrasjon'
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Verdi'
      },
      plotLines: [Highcharts.merge(plotLinesOption,{value: 932, label:{text: 'Theoretical mean: 932'}})]
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Observations',
      data: [
          [760, 801, 848, 895, 965],
          [733, 853, 939, 980, 1080],
          [714, 762, 817, 870, 918],
          [724, 802, 806, 871, 950],
          [834, 836, 864, 882, 910]
      ],
      tooltip: {
          headerFormat: '<em>Experiment No {point.key}</em><br/>'
        }
        },
        {
        name: 'Outlier',
        data: [ // x, y positions where 0 is the first category
          [0, 644],
          [4, 718],
          [4, 951],
          [4, 969]
        ],
        tooltip: {
          pointFormat: 'Observation: {point.y}'
        }
        }]
    });

  var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'indikator2',
    },
    title: {
      text: '<span data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip" data-disable-hover="false" tabindex="1" title="Help text that goes next to the chart title"><i class="ion-help"></i></span> Arbeidsledige'
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Verdi'
      },
      plotLines: [Highcharts.merge(plotLinesOption,{value: 932, label:{text: 'Theoretical mean: 932'}})]
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Observations',
      data: [
          [760, 801, 848, 895, 965],
          [733, 853, 939, 980, 1080],
          [714, 762, 817, 870, 918],
          [724, 802, 806, 871, 950],
          [834, 836, 864, 882, 910]
      ],
      tooltip: {
          headerFormat: '<em>Experiment No {point.key}</em><br/>'
        }
        },
        {
        name: 'Outlier',
        data: [ // x, y positions where 0 is the first category
          [0, 644],
          [4, 718],
          [4, 951],
          [4, 969]
        ],
        tooltip: {
          pointFormat: 'Observation: {point.y}'
        }
        }]
    });

  var chart3 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'indikator3',
    },
    title: {
      text: '<span data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip" data-disable-hover="false" tabindex="1" title="Help text that goes next to the chart title"><i class="ion-help"></i></span> Arbeidsledige Ungdom'
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Verdi'
      },
      plotLines: [Highcharts.merge(plotLinesOption,{value: 932, label:{text: 'Theoretical mean: 932'}})]
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Observations',
      data: [
          [760, 801, 848, 895, 965],
          [733, 853, 939, 980, 1080],
          [714, 762, 817, 870, 918],
          [724, 802, 806, 871, 950],
          [834, 836, 864, 882, 910]
      ],
      tooltip: {
          headerFormat: '<em>Experiment No {point.key}</em><br/>'
        }
        },
        {
        name: 'Outlier',
        data: [ // x, y positions where 0 is the first category
          [0, 644],
          [4, 718],
          [4, 951],
          [4, 969]
        ],
        tooltip: {
          pointFormat: 'Observation: {point.y}'
        }
        }]
    });

  var chart4 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'indikator4',
    },
    title: {
      text: '<span data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip" data-disable-hover="false" tabindex="1" title="Help text that goes next to the chart title"><i class="ion-help"></i></span> Ensidig næringsstruktur (Herfindal-index)'
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Verdi'
      },
      plotLines: [Highcharts.merge(plotLinesOption,{value: 932, label:{text: 'Theoretical mean: 932'}})]
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Observations',
      data: [
          [760, 801, 848, 895, 965],
          [733, 853, 939, 980, 1080],
          [714, 762, 817, 870, 918],
          [724, 802, 806, 871, 950],
          [834, 836, 864, 882, 910]
      ],
      tooltip: {
          headerFormat: '<em>Experiment No {point.key}</em><br/>'
        }
        },
        {
        name: 'Outlier',
        data: [ // x, y positions where 0 is the first category
          [0, 644],
          [4, 718],
          [4, 951],
          [4, 969]
        ],
        tooltip: {
          pointFormat: 'Observation: {point.y}'
        }
        }]
    });

  var chart5 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'indikator5',
    },
    title: {
      text: '<span data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip" data-disable-hover="false" tabindex="1" title="Help text that goes next to the chart title"><i class="ion-help"></i></span> Ensidig næringsstruktur i Privat sektor (Herfindal-index)'
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Verdi'
      },
      plotLines: [Highcharts.merge(plotLinesOption,{value: 932, label:{text: 'Theoretical mean: 932'}})]
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Observations',
      data: [
          [760, 801, 848, 895, 965],
          [733, 853, 939, 980, 1080],
          [714, 762, 817, 870, 918],
          [724, 802, 806, 871, 950],
          [834, 836, 864, 882, 910]
      ],
      tooltip: {
          headerFormat: '<em>Experiment No {point.key}</em><br/>'
        }
        },
        {
        name: 'Outlier',
        data: [ // x, y positions where 0 is the first category
          [0, 644],
          [4, 718],
          [4, 951],
          [4, 969]
        ],
        tooltip: {
          pointFormat: 'Observation: {point.y}'
        }
        }]
    });

  var chart6 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'indikator6',
    },
    title: {
      text: '<span data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip" data-disable-hover="false" tabindex="1" title="Help text that goes next to the chart title"><i class="ion-help"></i></span> Konkurranseutsatte næringer'
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Verdi'
      },
      plotLines: [Highcharts.merge(plotLinesOption,{value: 932, label:{text: 'Theoretical mean: 932'}})]
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Observations',
      data: [
          [760, 801, 848, 895, 965],
          [733, 853, 939, 980, 1080],
          [714, 762, 817, 870, 918],
          [724, 802, 806, 871, 950],
          [834, 836, 864, 882, 910]
      ],
      tooltip: {
          headerFormat: '<em>Experiment No {point.key}</em><br/>'
        }
        },
        {
        name: 'Outlier',
        data: [ // x, y positions where 0 is the first category
          [0, 644],
          [4, 718],
          [4, 951],
          [4, 969]
        ],
        tooltip: {
          pointFormat: 'Observation: {point.y}'
        }
        }]
    });

  var chart7 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'indikator7',
    },
    title: {
      text: '<span data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip" data-disable-hover="false" tabindex="1" title="Help text that goes next to the chart title"><i class="ion-help"></i></span> Naturbaserte næringer'
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Verdi'
      },
      plotLines: [Highcharts.merge(plotLinesOption,{value: 932, label:{text: 'Theoretical mean: 932'}})]
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Observations',
      data: [
          [760, 801, 848, 895, 965],
          [733, 853, 939, 980, 1080],
          [714, 762, 817, 870, 918],
          [724, 802, 806, 871, 950],
          [834, 836, 864, 882, 910]
      ],
      tooltip: {
          headerFormat: '<em>Experiment No {point.key}</em><br/>'
        }
        },
        {
        name: 'Outlier',
        data: [ // x, y positions where 0 is the first category
          [0, 644],
          [4, 718],
          [4, 951],
          [4, 969]
        ],
        tooltip: {
          pointFormat: 'Observation: {point.y}'
        }
        }]
    });

  var chart8 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'indikator8',
    },
    title: {
      text: '<span data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip" data-disable-hover="false" tabindex="1" title="Help text that goes next to the chart title"><i class="ion-help"></i></span> Offentlige arbeidsplasser'
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Verdi'
      },
      plotLines: [Highcharts.merge(plotLinesOption,{value: 932, label:{text: 'Theoretical mean: 932'}})]
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Observations',
      data: [
          [760, 801, 848, 895, 965],
          [733, 853, 939, 980, 1080],
          [714, 762, 817, 870, 918],
          [724, 802, 806, 871, 950],
          [834, 836, 864, 882, 910]
      ],
      tooltip: {
          headerFormat: '<em>Experiment No {point.key}</em><br/>'
        }
        },
        {
        name: 'Outlier',
        data: [ // x, y positions where 0 is the first category
          [0, 644],
          [4, 718],
          [4, 951],
          [4, 969]
        ],
        tooltip: {
          pointFormat: 'Observation: {point.y}'
        }
        }]
    });

  var chart9 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'indikator9',
    },
    title: {
      text: '<span data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip" data-disable-hover="false" tabindex="1" title="Help text that goes next to the chart title"><i class="ion-help"></i></span> Utdanningsnivå'
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Verdi'
      },
      plotLines: [Highcharts.merge(plotLinesOption,{value: 932, label:{text: 'Theoretical mean: 932'}})]
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Observations',
      data: [
          [760, 801, 848, 895, 965],
          [733, 853, 939, 980, 1080],
          [714, 762, 817, 870, 918],
          [724, 802, 806, 871, 950],
          [834, 836, 864, 882, 910]
      ],
      tooltip: {
          headerFormat: '<em>Experiment No {point.key}</em><br/>'
        }
        },
        {
        name: 'Outlier',
        data: [ // x, y positions where 0 is the first category
          [0, 644],
          [4, 718],
          [4, 951],
          [4, 969]
        ],
        tooltip: {
          pointFormat: 'Observation: {point.y}'
        }
        }]
    });

  var chart10 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'indikator10',
    },
    title: {
      text: '<span data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip" data-disable-hover="false" tabindex="1" title="Help text that goes next to the chart title"><i class="ion-help"></i></span> Forsørgelserbyrde'
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Verdi'
      },
      plotLines: [Highcharts.merge(plotLinesOption,{value: 932, label:{text: 'Theoretical mean: 932'}})]
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Observations',
      data: [
          [760, 801, 848, 895, 965],
          [733, 853, 939, 980, 1080],
          [714, 762, 817, 870, 918],
          [724, 802, 806, 871, 950],
          [834, 836, 864, 882, 910]
      ],
      tooltip: {
          headerFormat: '<em>Experiment No {point.key}</em><br/>'
        }
        },
        {
        name: 'Outlier',
        data: [ // x, y positions where 0 is the first category
          [0, 644],
          [4, 718],
          [4, 951],
          [4, 969]
        ],
        tooltip: {
          pointFormat: 'Observation: {point.y}'
        }
        }]
    });

  var chart11 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'indikator11',
    },
    title: {
      text: '<span data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip" data-disable-hover="false" tabindex="1" title="Help text that goes next to the chart title"><i class="ion-help"></i></span> Forsørgelsesbyrde Eldre'
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Verdi'
      },
      plotLines: [Highcharts.merge(plotLinesOption,{value: 932, label:{text: 'Theoretical mean: 932'}})]
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Observations',
      data: [
          [760, 801, 848, 895, 965],
          [733, 853, 939, 980, 1080],
          [714, 762, 817, 870, 918],
          [724, 802, 806, 871, 950],
          [834, 836, 864, 882, 910]
      ],
      tooltip: {
          headerFormat: '<em>Experiment No {point.key}</em><br/>'
        }
        },
        {
        name: 'Outlier',
        data: [ // x, y positions where 0 is the first category
          [0, 644],
          [4, 718],
          [4, 951],
          [4, 969]
        ],
        tooltip: {
          pointFormat: 'Observation: {point.y}'
        }
    }]
    });
});
```

Comment: What you have in your fiddle seems OK to me so far ... did you want each chart title to have a different icon?

Comment: no, I want the icon that I have already, right above y axis and title text centered, it is not like that now

Comment: OK, now I see what you want. Let me think of an idea.

Comment: I don't think that it makes sense to use the chart title for this.  I would look at either the **labels** property, or the **renderer** function:  http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#labels | http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**jlbriggs** definitely has the more practical solution in mind. I tried the `labels` idea out to little success, but the `renderer` function works very well for this task.

You want to add the renderer code at the end of your chart options, as its own function (see also the updated fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/mu9wswv3/10/).

```
// the rest of your chart options go here
...
    }, function (chart) { // on complete
        chart.renderer.html('<span data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip" data-disable-hover="false" tabindex="1" title="Help text that goes next to the chart title"><i class="ion-help"></i></span>', 50, 30) .css({ color: 'black', fontSize: '20px' }).add();
    }
});
```

Here's how this will appear in your chart (the red arrow is just my annotation to help show the icon's position):

[image]

Please let me know if this solves your question.

Comment: Awesome! Please let me know if you have any other questions for this particular project; I'm happy to help.

Comment: Thank you very much! Actually, I do have another question for the same project, I have updated fiddle in it with your solution for icons, the link is:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37329702/highcharts-tooltip-hover-position

Comment: Great! I'll check that out later this evening or tomorrow and see if I can get you a suitable answer.

Comment: Thank you again, I really appreciated it!